# Disable dynamic elements -angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this static element

```
<sp-attachment-button ng-if="::data.canWrite &amp;&amp; data.canAttach"
                      id="disableElements" class="ng-scope">
</sp-attachment-button>
```

when `ng-if` condition is true, some sub elements will be added dynamically

```
<sp-attachment-button ng-if="::data.canWrite &amp;&amp; data.canAttach"
                      id="disableElements" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="file-upload-input">
        <input type="file" style="display: none" multiple="true"
               ng-file-select="data.onFileSelect($files)"
               class="sp-attachments-input">
        <button title="Add attachment"
                ng-click="attachmentHandler.openSelector($event)"
                class="panel-button sp-attachment-add btn btn-link"
                aria-label="Add attachment" role="button">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</sp-attachment-button>
```

Now I need to disable the `button` element here.So I tried by adding following options to the `<sp-attachment-button>` element

```
1.disabled='disabled'
2.ng-disabled='true'
```

But it doesn't work.How can I disable the `button` element?
Any suggestion guys?

`Note:` I can see only the `<sp-attachment-button>` element.

Comment: Why not add `ng-disabled` to `button` element itself instead of `<sp-attachment-button>`?

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 kindly read my question fully.button is a dynamic element I cant see it.

Comment: Can you please show how you are generating dynamic content/element?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add id to that button then here is the solution.

```
document.getElementsByClass("buttonId").disabled = true;
```